# Finding X with cdf $F(x)=1-\exp\left(-x^3\right)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose the following cdf $F(x)=1-\exp\left(-x^3\right), x \geq 0$ .

How can I generate a stochastic variable $X$ with this cdf using the function `runif()` in R?
Is it something like that you generate $U$ with `runif()` and then you compute $X=F^{-1}(U)$, where $F$ is the cdf of $X$?

Comment: Precisely. In this case we can find an explicit formula for $F^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct. To find the inverse to $y = 1 - \exp \left(-x^3\right)$ analytically, transpose $x,y$ and solve for the new $y$:
$$\begin{align}
x &= 1 - \exp \left(-y^3 \right) \\
1-x &= \exp \left(-y^3 \right) \\
y^3 &= -\ln (1-x) \\
y &= \sqrt[3]{ -\ln (1-x)} = \sqrt[3]{ \ln \left(\frac{1}{1-x} \right)}
\end{align}
$$
so you would compute $X = \sqrt[3]{ -\ln (1-U)}$ for the random variable with cdf $F(x)$.

Comment: It must be $y=1−exp(x^3)$

Comment: @RoosJansen thanks for the good eye, made changes